# remove class at bottom of page

Tags: jquery, css

I have a fixed position nav which fades in as the user scrolls down the page. When they get to the bottom of the page the nav needs to stop above the footer.

As a work around I've defined the height of the containing div and used..

```
var floatnav = $(".floatingnavfix");
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 4780) {
        floatnav.removeClass('floatingnavfix').addClass("floatingnavab");
    } 
    else {
        floatnav.removeClass("floatingnavab").addClass('floatingnavfix');
    }
});
```

to absolute position the nav above the footer.

The above has worked ok but to use the layout on a variety of pages I cant define a fixed height.

Can anyone point me in the direction of a solution? Is it possible to remove a class and add another depending on the % of the page that's been scrolled through? or maybe when the nav reaches an anchor?

Comment: I'm fairly sure you can do this with [waypoints](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-waypoints/info) out-of-the-box. Have you considered using it?

Comment: Using $(document).height(); would get the height of your page. You could then use this value to workout the percentage you would like to hit.

Comment: @blgt I agree that using waypoints seems to be the best for his case.

Comment: I will look into waypoints

Answer (score 1):

### Method 1

> Is it possible to remove a class and add another depending on the % of the page that's been scrolled through?

Yes, instead of using a manual value to check your scroll:

```
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

if (scroll >= 4780)
```

You can calculate the % instead:

```
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
var pageHeight = $(document).height();
var percent = scroll / pageHeight * 100;

if (percent >= 90)
```

### Method 2

> or when the nav reaches an anchor?

This is also possible:

```
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
var anchorPoint = $("#element").offset().top;

if (scroll >= anchorPoint)
```

### Method 3

Since you are focusing the event around your footer, you can also calculate whether the user has reached the footer in his screen or not:

```
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
var footerPosition = $("#footer").offset().top;
var screenHeight = $(window).height();

if (scroll >= (footerPosition - screenHeight) )
```

### Method 4

You could even calculate whether your navigation div is touching the footer. There are a lot of possibilities.

```
var footerPosition = $("#footer").offset().top;
var navHeight = $("#nav").height();
var navPosition = $("#nav").offset().top;
var margin = 20; // I assume you want a little bit of spacing 
                 // inbetween the nav and the footer

if ( (navPosition + navHeight + margin) >= footerPosition )
```

Comment: Thanks for all of this. Looking at the answer you've given I'm starting to realise that the biggest stumbling block is creating a containing div that's 100% of the page height.

Comment: @DaveHudson You don't need a containing div like that for any of my given examples.